# Cannot open GUI editors in superuser mode

Tags: sudo, editors, gedit

I was trying to edit my `sources.list` in order to add local mirror information. I am not comfortable with command line editors, so I tried using `sudo mousepad /etc/apt/sources.list`.

I got the following error report.

```
No protocol specified

(mousepad:4942): Mousepad-ERROR **: Cannot open display:
```

I tried several other editors such as gedit, kwrite etc. but I get similar error reports.

```
No protocol specified

** (gedit:4957): WARNING **: Could not open X display
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:4957): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
```

I am on a local 64 bit system running Debian Jessie.

Comment: I found http://askubuntu.com/a/414810/615414, but it involves editing /etc/visudo; I know; it's ironic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn’t run an editor as root to edit system files, you should use `sudoedit` (especially since you have `sudo` set up already). That will make a copy of the file, that you can edit, open it in the editor of your choice, wait for you to finish editing it, and if you make changes to it, copy it back over the system file.

In a little more detail, you’d run something like

```
SUDO_EDITOR="gedit -w" sudoedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

This will:

- check that you’re allowed to edit the file (according to the `sudo` configuration in `/etc/sudoers`; yours should be OK already);
- copy `/etc/apt/sources.list` to a temporary file and make it editable for you;
- start `gedit` with the temporary file;
- wait for you to close the file (this is why we need the `-w` option);
- check whether you made changes to the temporary file, and if so, copy it over the original file.

You can set `SUDO_EDITOR` up permanently in your shell’s startup files (*e.g.* `~/.bashrc`). If it’s not defined, `sudoedit` will also check `VISUAL` and `EDITOR`. You can specify any editor you like, as long as it’s capable of waiting for an editing session to finish.

Answer (score 0):

Input `sudo apt edit-sources` to open your sources list in nano.