# Wait for forking process to complete

Tags: bash, xdg-open

I have an application which does this:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
gedit $tmpfile && pkexec mv $tmpfile $1
```

Works great.  It creates a temp file, opens it in a graphical editor, and it gets moved to a correct spot with elevated permissions using polkit when I'm done.

But... you need to have gedit installed. I'd prefer to use something which respects the user's desktop environment and preferences.  `xdg-open` should work but I have a problem:

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
xdg-open $tmpfile && pkexec mv $tmpfile $1
```

`xdg-open` is a forking process.  It will launch the editor, then return immediately... causing the `mv` to be triggered before I've had a chance to work.

Is there a way for me to only trigger the `pkexec mv ...` after the editor completes?

[`xdg-open(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xdg-open) doesn't offer any help.  Am I going to need to write some kind of `inotify` tool to block until some event is read from an FD?

Comment: This looks like you’re reinventing `sudoedit`, but the latter’s UX might not match your expectations.

Comment: I'm actually doing this from C in an un-privilaged GUI app.  I'm launching processes in the manner shown in bash (so it's honestly not a bash-specific question).  Instead of writing my own editor, I thought it would be best to use the default.  Also, since my app isn't elevated I'm relying on `pkexec`.  `sudo` and `sudoedit` don't really work well from inside of an unprivilaged GUI.  Actually, writing to a tempfile with the user's editor, then moving it was an idea I got from `visudo`.

Comment: Right, I get that (hence my comment about the UX). Your question is really about waiting for an edit operation to complete, and that’s rather difficult. Try opening one file in `gedit`, then running your first example — the temporary file will open in the running editor and your `pkexec` will proceed without waiting. Some editors can be asked to wait (see [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356443/86440)), but `xdg-open` doesn’t have anything equivalent.

Comment: You could rely on [`mimeopen -n`](https://manpages.debian.org/libfile-mimeinfo-perl/mimeopen.1p) instead

Comment: @A.B Yes, this works!  I was about halfway through implementing `inotify` when I saw your answer.

Comment: Watch out, `mimeopen` doesn’t necessarily wait either, it doesn’t do anything special; on my system, opening with `gedit` using `mimeopen` doesn’t wait if the editor is already running.